# Docker build fails, getting: failed to connect to proxy No route to host

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to set Prelude SIEM on docker container by following this repository:

https://hub.docker.com/r/2xyo/prelude-siem

When I try to build the container with:

docker build -t prelude .

I get a curl error when trying to reach to the proxy server:

```
sumaia@main-srv:~/core/docker-prelude-siem$ docker build -t prelude .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  157.2kB
Step 1/37 : FROM centos:centos7
 ---> eeb6ee3f44bd
Step 2/37 : MAINTAINER 2xyo
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 067affd319d1
Step 3/37 : ARG PRELUDE_VERSION
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 52efc46cd210
Step 4/37 : ENV PRELUDE_VERSION ${PRELUDE_VERSION:-1.2.6}
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 34dfd4af7e35
Step 5/37 : RUN mkdir -p /opt/prelude-src
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8ed92176b862
Step 6/37 : WORKDIR /opt/prelude-src
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 817dd04576b6
Step 7/37 : RUN curl https://www.prelude-siem.org/attachments/download/408/libpreludedb-${PRELUDE_VERSION}.tar.gz | tar xz &&     curl https://www.prelude-siem.org/attachments/download/409/prelude-correlator-${PRELUDE_VERSION}.tar.gz | tar xz &&     curl https://www.prelude-siem.org/attachments/download/410/libprelude-${PRELUDE_VERSION}.tar.gz | tar xz &&     curl https://www.prelude-siem.org/attachments/download/411/prelude-lml-${PRELUDE_VERSION}.tar.gz | tar xz &&     curl https://www.prelude-siem.org/attachments/download/412/prelude-lml-rules-${PRELUDE_VERSION}.tar.gz | tar xz &&     curl https://www.prelude-siem.org/attachments/download/413/prewikka-${PRELUDE_VERSION}.tar.gz | tar xz &&     curl https://www.prelude-siem.org/attachments/download/414/prelude-manager-${PRELUDE_VERSION}.tar.gz | tar xz
 ---> Running in 738d226a8f9f
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:03 --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed connect to <Proxy IP>:80; No route to host

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
The command '/bin/sh -c curl https://www.prelude-siem.org/attachments/download/408/libpreludedb-${PRELUDE_VERSION}.tar.gz | tar xz &&     curl https://www.prelude-siem.org/attachments/download/409/prelude-correlator-${PRELUDE_VERSION}.tar.gz | tar xz &&     curl https://www.prelude-siem.org/attachments/download/410/libprelude-${PRELUDE_VERSION}.tar.gz | tar xz &&     curl https://www.prelude-siem.org/attachments/download/411/prelude-lml-${PRELUDE_VERSION}.tar.gz | tar xz &&     curl https://www.prelude-siem.org/attachments/download/412/prelude-lml-rules-${PRELUDE_VERSION}.tar.gz | tar xz &&     curl https://www.prelude-siem.org/attachments/download/413/prewikka-${PRELUDE_VERSION}.tar.gz | tar xz &&     curl https://www.prelude-siem.org/attachments/download/414/prelude-manager-${PRELUDE_VERSION}.tar.gz | tar xz' returned a non-zero code: 2
sumaia@main-srv:~/core/docker-prelude-siem$
```

My network is behind proxy, and it has been working on my machine without issues for some time, and docker is able to pull images without issues, here is my ~/.docker/config.json file content:

```
{
        "auths": {
                "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
                        "auth": "c29tYXl5YWhtb2hkOnZDZ3Y1ampBTThuZ1NNOA=="
                }
        },
        "HttpHeaders": {
                "User-Agent": "Docker-Client/19.03.12 (linux)"
        },
        "proxies": {
                "default": {
                        "httpProxy": "http://<proxy IP>:80",
                        "httpsProxy": "http://<proxy IP>:80",
                        "noProxy": "*.internaldomain.net"
                }
        }
}
```

am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was due to an old interface that is not disabled, after disabling it, the issue was fixed.